# css on active element but not it's border

Tags: css

I'm making mobile apps in which there are several `span` tags in the html and I have applied border to the span without defining the color so that the border would be as per it's color.

[here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fapr39e7/)

So now, I wanted to change the color of `span` tags on `active` but not it's border-color and this is why I was trying to make it by setting `initial` value but seems there's no support for the initial value in border-color.

```
span:active{
    color: red;
    border-color: initial;
}
```

---

I can manage each colored element active state border-color but it takes a lot of works. Is there any standard way to make element change on its element only but not on it's border?

Comment: when used on borders `initial` means the border will make use of the `color` css - meaning this will change it to red: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `border-color: inherit`:

```
span:active{
    color: red;
    border-color: inherit;
}
```

Take a look here: [box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#border-color-properties)

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fapr39e7/1/)

Answer (score 3):

use inherit not initial.

```
border-color: inherit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing from initial to inherit will do the trick

```
span:active{
color: red;
border-color: inherit;
}
```

**Working JS Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/fapr39e7/2/